# Better way to design table

Tags: mongodb, database-design, indexing

I'm designing a database table which stores all the queries searched by a user (so that I can use it for autosuggestions). Also, I wanted to store data like who searched it and time the query happened.

I have two approaches in mind:

```
{
  _id: "some-random-value-1",
  query: "this is the query",
  user: "username-1",
  date: "query-time-1"
}

{
  _id: "some-random-value-2",
  query: "this is the query",
  user: "username-2",
  date: "query-time-2"
}
```

and:

```
{
  _id: "some-random-value",
  query: "this is the query",
  query-details: [
                   {user: "username-1", date:"query-time-1"},
                   {user: "username-2", date:"query-time-2"}
                 ]
}
```

As you can see, the first one saves multiple queries of the same search query.

So, which is the better way of the two (suggest if there is an even better one) even if in the future if I wanted details like getting count of queries etc.

Comment: Designs with unconstrained document growth won't work well in many NoSql databases, including MongoDb. mongoDb documents may not exceed 16MB in size. While that is large, you'd need to consider what happens when it is hit. Either structure could work if you weren't worried about that, you need to consider what types of queries you'll need and how to apply them to your structures.

Comment: Ok. Also i wanted to index the query. In case 1 wont that be an issue

Comment: It won't be an issue likely in the second choice either depending on queries needed. I'd suggest reading more of the Data modeling guidelines on the MongoDB web site to gain further insight as to the pros and cons of various models.

Comment: I feel that case 1 is better as we don't have to search and insert. which is easier too.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it depends on how you are going to insert/update and query the data. Without knowing it I wouldn't dare to suggest any solution but I may share some thoughts which you might find helpful.

First of all I assume you want to store only unique queries per a user so it's easier to query them for autosuggestion. If yes, I would basicly go with your first option adding some more sure to it.

1. I would always **UPSERT** a new query-user entry. That is insert it if it doesn't exist and update **DATE** field if it does. There's a special command setting for this in mongo so you don't have to search first to check if it exists or not.
2. I would create a unique index on user and query fields. This will insure that user-query combintation is unique and it will be a **COVERING** index for your main query which I suppose is user-query search to return query field. This should be really fast.
3. Also if you don't want to bother a user by suggesting queries he didn't use for long I would create a **time to live** index on **DATE** field so old queries are removed automatically by mongo

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok. Also, what is the best way to index a query string. Apparently, there is something called text index which helps if text search is enabled. But text search isn't suggested in production

Comment: Well, not sure what your query string looks like but I really doubt you need a text index, which is actually a full text index. Just create an ordinary index on user and query field, one compound index. This should be more than enough. Autosuggestion features usually search with simple CONTAINS filter so no full text search index is required here.